# 100% height div. Parent height determined by image with % width

Tags: css

I have a wrapper div containing a right floated 100% height div and an image.

The image has a width set in %. As you resize the browser window the image height increases and decreased taking with it the height of the wrapper div.

When I set a fixed height on the wrapper div, the right floated 100% height div increases in height as I want it. However, the wrapper div has a dynamic height, set by the current height of the image and the 100% height div, in this instance does not resize vertically as you'd expect.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable?

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/fraserhart/pen/qiFmb

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7v619Ip.jpg" />
  <div class="grid">
    <section class="row">
      <p>Home</p>   
    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <p>Looking For Care</p>   
    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <p>Working For Us</p> 
    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <p>Professionals</p>  
    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <p>Who We Are</p> 
    </section>

    <section class="row">
      <p>Find a Branch</p>  
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-fix"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  background:blue;
  height:auto;
}
img{
  width:60%;
}
.clear-fix{
  clear:both;
}
.grid {
  display: box;
  width:400px;
  height:100%;
  box-orient: vertical;
  background:#ff0000;
  float:right;
}
.row {
  padding: 20px;
  box-flex:1;
  background: #ccc;
  padding:0px 5px;
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: When the window re-sizes, the browser recalculates the image dimensions.  However, there is no way for the recalculated image dimensions to be communicated to the sibling element (`.grid`) hence the `.grid` is basing its height on the parent element and not the element immediately proceeding it in the document flow.  You wan work around this with JavaScript or jQuery.  Would you consider some other mark-up? This is a common CSS problem and worth some effort.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using jQuery out of stubbornness. Ha. May be the only way though.

Comment: How do you want the .grid element to behave upon window re-size?  Can you elaborate in your post?

Comment: You might also be able to use the [CSS `calc` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc), although bear in mind it's labeled as "at risk" in the spec.

Comment: I just want .grid to expand to 100% height based on the height of the .wrapper. .wrapper's height is determined by the height of the image

Comment: @Fraser and what about the `.row` elements in the grid, can these scale with the grid?

Comment: They can. It uses flexbox to do this

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is one way of doing it, a bit bizarre, probably not to be recommended, but it is a proof of concept, an odd CSS curiosity.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3tUfC/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image-port">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/800">
    </div>
    <div class="content-port">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/25">
                <p>First...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/25">
                <p>Second...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/25">
                <p>Third...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/25">
                <p>Fourth...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
}

.image-port {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60%;
}
.image-port img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.content-port {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: wheat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
}

.content-port .grid {
}

.content-port .row {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
}
.content-port .row:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

.content-port .row img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.content-port .row p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

### How It Works

A `.wrapper` block contains two `table-cell` elements: `.image-port` and `.content-port`,
with relative widths of 60% and 40% respectively.  This avoids the problem of having the grid jump beneath the image for small window sizes.

In the `.image-port`, let the `img` scale to 100% width to get a good view of the image.

In the `.content-port` block element, set the `position: relative`, and optionally, `overflow` and a few other properties for visual design.

Here is the trick: in each `.row`, place a image with a certain aspect ratio.  I created four rows so my image as a 4:1 aspect ratio.  Set the `.row img` width to 100% and set the `visibility: hidden` so that the image takes up flexible space but is out of the way.  This will allow each row row to change in size as you re-size the window.

Next, place your content in the `.row`, for example, a `p`.  the content element is `position: absolute` such that it takes up the full width and height of the `.row` parent element (set the offset properties to zero).

The rows now have a height that scales with the width of the window.  This approach has some flexibility, and though not perfect, may be useful.

Note that if you stretch the window wide enough, the 100x25 images will be their full width and the `.grid` will move away from the right edge of the wrapper.  You can allow for this by using a larger placeholder image, say 1000x250.

If you make the placeholder image as a transparent gif or png, is should be light weight and since you are using the same image multiple times, the browser should really be making one request for it (I think?).

**The Quirk** about this approach is that how well the grid expands depends a bit on the aspect ration of the image in the image-port.  You will need to experiment a bit and try to optimize the various parameters to get a pleasing layout.